# Flutter Android Sign In With Apple

Tags: android, firebase, flutter, apple-sign-in

I'm wanting to use `Sign In With Apple` on `Android` via `Flutter` but not having much luck.

I'm stuck on getting an `invalid_request`. Invalid client id or web redirect url.

I'm using `Firebase` so my `redirectUri` is what's provided in Firebase & my `clientId` is my bundle id from Apple.

Is there any additional setup I need?

Comment: I'm getting the same error, but not any solution bro.